LDO Regulation problem MCP1725
I have got this adjustable LDO configured for 1.2 V output. In my design I have the exact values and connection as in datasheet. SHDN signal is connected directly and fixed to pins 1 and 2 with a 0 ohm resistor.
The thing is that the output is 3.3 V, so not regulation is found. What can be the problem? I have tried two components, so it is not the IC itself. What am I missing?
ADJ pin is 1.085 V (according to datasheet it should be 0.41V).

Measured VIN = 3.33V.
Measured VOUT = 3.33 V.
Measured ADJ = 1.085 V.
Measured SHDN pin 3 = 3.33 V.




Double check your resistors.

If you short R1 and take out R2, have you 2.5V at output?

@Antonio51 If I do that, I get my 1.2V. That was he problem, the P/N was a fixed one, not the adjustable one.

You should first check that the input is not shorted to the output.
This adjustable LDO has also fixed variants with 3.3V, make sure that you did order the right version and that the markings are right. From the datasheet you linked:


That was the problem. I was using adjustable configuration with the resistors but I needed to used the schematic found in the datasheet for the fixed output one, because I ordered the fixed 1.2V output version. I wasn't able to find why the exact resistors did not work. Thanks!
